# How to distinguish between mutli-part form data of empty file and missing file?

Tags: http, file-upload, multipartform-data

I try on server side to distinguish between the upload of empty file and not-uploaded file

The POST body content of an empty file is:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAYxCGhPMYcmdkdlv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_1"

dd
------WebKitFormBoundaryAYxCGhPMYcmdkdlv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_2"; filename="foo"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryAYxCGhPMYcmdkdlv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_3"

Upload
------WebKitFormBoundaryAYxCGhPMYcmdkdlv--
```

While missing file is

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryMldAHhbBqWpKPlRY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_1"

dd
------WebKitFormBoundaryMldAHhbBqWpKPlRY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_2"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryMldAHhbBqWpKPlRY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_3"

Upload
------WebKitFormBoundaryMldAHhbBqWpKPlRY--
```

The only difference is `filename=` content one is empty other contains the file name (same behavior for Firefox and Chromium)

Questions:

1. Are there any conditions that browser wouldn't provide a `filename` (security or something like that)?
2. Is it actually valid/standard way to distinguish between empty file and non-set file, please provide reference.
3. Is `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` is standard response and it will be set in case of non-uploaded file?

I'd like to see some references to standards that confirm or disprove my observations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Filename

The original specification for **"Form-based File Upload in HTML"** was [RFC1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867)

According to that specification, the `filename` parameter

> "is not required, but is strongly recommended in any case where the original filename is known"

This spec was superceded by [RFC2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) -  **"Returning Values from Forms:  multipart/form-data"**, which states

> The sending application MAY supply a file name ... as specified in [RFC2184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2184);

(where RFC2184 goes on to stress its importance, without requiring it)

Note that it refers to "the sending application". The spec makes it clear that it is application agnostic.
For a cross-browser view on actual implementation however, Mozilla's MDN documentation for `FormData` sheds some light on it.
In the context of [`FormData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) where a file/blob is *set* but filename is not set explicitly:

> The default filename for Blob objects is "blob". The default filename for File objects is the file's filename.

### 2. Difference between empty & no file

To answer this, it's important to note [Section 5.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388#section-5.7) of RFC2388 - **"Correlating form data with the original form"**

> This specification provides no specific mechanism by which
> multipart/form-data can be associated with the form that caused it to
> be transmitted. This separation is intentional...

This *is* answered in the HTML5 specification however, which details [how form data is constructed](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#sec-constructing-the-form-data-set).

> ...if the field element is an `<input>` element whose type attribute is in the File Upload state, then for each file selected in the `<input>` element, append an entry to the form data set with the *name* as the name, the file (consisting of the name, the type, and the body) as the value, and *type* as the type. **If there are no selected files, then append an entry to the form data set with the name as the name, the empty string as the value, and application/octet-stream as the type.**

This matches your observation above.

Looking to how a real-world server implementation deals with this, take the PHP runtime as an example.
Its API makes no distinction between "no file" and "empty file" - and will raise a single error `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` in either case.

As PHP is open source (written in C), you can see that implementation [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/rfc1867.c)

### 3. MIME content-type encoding

This is answered in #2 above - As detailed in the HTML5 spec, (from a compliant browser) it will always be `application/octet-stream` where the form value is empty.

For completeness, if a file *is* provided, RFC2388 specifies that:

> If the contents of a file are returned via filling out a form, then the file input is identified as the appropriate media type, if known, or "application/octet-stream"

Comment: Wow - excellent answer - thank you very much!